# What may be the cause of pretty slow training speed for CNN (transfer learning)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu, conv-neural-network

I use GPU for training a model with transfer learning from Inception v3.
Weights='imagenet'. The convolution base is frozen and dense layers on top are used for 10 classes classification for MNIST digit recognition.
The code is the following:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    #rescale=1./255,
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input,
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    zoom_range = 0.1, # Randomly zoom image 
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False) 
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_path,
target_size=(224, 224),
color_mode="rgb",
class_mode="categorical",
batch_size=86,
interpolation="bilinear",
)

test_generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(
test_path,
target_size=(224, 224),
color_mode="rgb",
class_mode="categorical",
batch_size=86,
interpolation="bilinear",
)
#Import pre-trained model InceptionV3
from keras.applications import InceptionV3

#Instantiate convolutional base
conv_base = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
                    include_top=False,
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3))  # 3 = number of channels in RGB pictures
#Forbid training of conv part
 conv_base.trainable=False
#Build model
 model=Sequential()
 model.add(conv_base)
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

 # Define the optimizer
 optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

 # Compile the model
 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'] ) 

 history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          epochs = 1, validation_data = test_generator,
                          verbose = 2, steps_per_epoch=60000 // 86)
                          #, callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])
```

The obtained training rate was 1 epoch/hour (even after reducing lr to 0.001), when I used rescale=1./255 for data generator.

After searching for answers, I found that the cause my be in not appropriate form for input.

When I tried to use preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input,
I received a message after 30 min of training:

```
Epoch 1/1
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 1449 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.
  UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 614 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.
  UserWarning)
```

What is wrong with the model?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The learning rate doesn't affect the training rate.

How fast you train the model depends on your gpu, you cpu, and IO on your drive, ceteris paribus.

First, check if your gpu is used for the training.

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

Next, is 32 the max batch_size your gpu can handle? Try increasing the batch_size until you get OOM error.

Or you could monitor your gpu and cpu usage.

If gpu and cpu usage is not maxed, it may be limited by your drive IO speed.

Comment: Thank you, @Isaac  Ng. I use to check GPU usage before execution of my code. It works. Regarding the batch_size: When I tried the code on my local machine I got OOM error even when reducing batch_size to 8.  Now I'm experimenting on the Google colab (with GPU) and get the results described.

Comment: So were you using GPU? Btw your steps per epochs should be num_examples/batch_size.

Comment: Yes, the GPU was used in all tries.

Comment: If batch_size of 32 worked, a smaller batch_size shouldn't give a OOM error. Did you change anything else in the code?

Comment: On my local machine 32 didn't work, on colab did. I have 60000 samples and set batch_size=86 and so steps_per_epoch=60000 // 86. I'm still getting: Epoch 1/1
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 573 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.
  UserWarning)

Comment: Are you using your data from your google drive? Or did you transfer it to the colab drive. It could be due to queue timeout.

Mounting google drive on colab and using the files there limits the input speed by the internet transfer speed.

Comment: Yes, I mounted google drive on colab and read files from there. So should I upload my data to the colab?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong in the model.

For increasing the speed of epochs, try the following:

1. Switch on XLA.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True)
```

2. Use mixed precision

```
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

Comment: How does decreasing learning rate increase the time for epochs?

Comment: @Abhishek Verma, it helped in the sense that now I receive the warnings at once after having run the code. Before it was after 30 min.